# React not render div into li tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, react-rails

Cannot render this code, get **SyntaxError: [stdin]:4:1: unexpected indentation**

```
@Statement = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.li
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'statement'
        @props.statement.body
```

If i comment out that line number *4*, everything works fine.

Why it's happened? I can't understand anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code won't compile as you are trying to pass a react element as the only argument to `React.DOM.li`, while it expects first an options object, then a child object.

```
@Statement = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.li {},
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'statement'
        @props.statement.body
```

You need to pass the empty hash to the `li` element. You could pass `null` instead of `{}`, they will both be taken as an empty options / attr object by React.

Also, you can use the destructuring assignment from coffeescript to make the react code look cleaner:

```
{li, div} = React.DOM

@Statement = React.createClass
  render: ->
    li {},
      div
        className: 'statement'
        @props.statement.body
```

One of the few groups to work with coffeescript and React without JSX are Arkency, take a look at [their resources](http://blog.arkency.com/products/) for more tips.

---

## Edit: regarding your comment:

It is probably a case of indentation - Coffeescript implicitly returns the last expression's result in a function or block.

If you wanted to render the second span nested in the first:

```
render: -> 
  React.DOM.span null, 
    '123' 
    React.DOM.span null, 
      'sdfdfg'
```

And if you were looking to render the two as siblings, you will need to wrap them up in a parent element as you can only return one component from React's render method:

```
render: -> 
  React.DOM.div null, 
    React.DOM.span null, 
       '123' 
    React.DOM.span null, 
      'sdfdfg'
```

Comment: Thx)
May be u can explain me, why in this case is rendered only last span?

`render: ->
    React.DOM.span null,
        '123'
    React.DOM.span null,
      'sdfdfg'`

Comment: @nuT707 I added an edit to the answer regarding your comment. If it's not the right answer, please post a new question with proper indentation as that's very important with both React and Coffeescript